# drupal 8 - key board divider key after my favicon [ | ]

Tags: drupal-8

Good Afternoon,

I cannot figure out how to remove the key board divider key after my favicon in the browser tab. Please see the image below.

Note: I am developing with Drupal 8.

[image: key board divider key after my favicon]

Answer (score 1):

Drupal construct, by default, the page title such: [Entity-Title] | [Site Name].
**It's seems you don't have a title on this page.**

It depends which page(s) you try to change. For an Entity, just set the title field would fix your probleme.

**Titles on routes now can be set on various ways, depending on your use case.**
Previously (drupal-7) just `drupal_set_title()` was called in whatever place. The following use cases exist:

### Override title tag

You may override the title tag in the head of your HTML document using the `HOOK_preprocess_html`.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // Change the Title
  $variables['head_title']['title'] = 'Title';
  // Change the Suffix (sitename)
  $variables['head_title']['name'] = 'Suffix';
}
```

### Static title

For static titles you set a '_title' on the routing definition:

```
block.admin_add:
  path: '/admin/structure/block/add/{plugin_id}/{theme}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\block\Controller\BlockAddController::blockAddConfigureForm'
    _title: 'Configure block'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer blocks'
```

### Dynamic title

If you write a controller and you need a dynamic title, for example depending on the site configuration, use _title_callback in the route defaults.

```
mymodule.test:
  path: '/mymodule/test'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\TestController::getContent'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\TestController::getTitle'

<?php
class TestController {

  /**
  * Returns a page title.
  */
  public function getTitle() {
    // The \Drupal::config() should be injected instead of using static call.
    return  'Foo: ' . \Drupal::config()->get('system.site')->get('name');
  }

  /**
  * Returns a page render array.
  */
  public function getContent() {
    $build = array();
    $build['#markup'] = 'Hello Drupal';
    return $build;
  }
}
```

### Final title override

If you write a controller and you need to override the title from the route, you can return #title in the render array. This should generally to be avoided, since the title for the page when fully rendered could be different from the title in other contexts (like in the breadcrumb).

```
<?php
class TestController {

  /**
  * Renders a page with a title.
  *
  * @return array
  *   A render array as expected by drupal_render()
  */
  public function getContentWithTitle() {
    $build = array();
    $build['#markup'] = 'Hello Drupal';
    // The \Drupal::config() should be injected instead of using static call.
    $build['#title'] = 'Foo: ' . Drupal::config()->get('system.site')->get('name');

    return $build;
  }

}
```

### drupal_set_title() in Drupal 8

As you can see [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2067859) that `drupal_set_title()` is deprecated in Drupal 8.

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
if ($route = $request->attributes->get(\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT)) {
  $route->setDefault('_title', 'New Title');
}
```